# Contents of JScrollPane are not visible

Tags: java, swing

I have a main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hex");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JComponent inputs = new InputPanel();
        JComponent hexGrid = new HexGridPanel(10,10,30);
        JComponent outputs = new OutputPanel();
        JComponent toolbar = new ToolbarPanel(); // This one is having problems

        Container pane = frame.getContentPane();

        pane.add(inputs,  BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        pane.add(hexGrid, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pane.add(outputs, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        pane.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.PAGE_END); // This one is having problems

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And all of my other panels work except for `ToolbarPanel` that for some reason does not show its content:

```
public ToolbarPanel(){

    JPanel content = new JPanel();
    content.setLayout(new BoxLayout(content, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

    ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();

    JRadioButton button = new JRadioButton("Test");
    buttonGroup.add(button );
    content.add(button );

    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(content);
    scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    content.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
    scroll.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GREEN));

    this.add(scroll);
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 200));
    this.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK)); // Only this is showing up in the UI

}
```

The `ToolbarPanel` itself shows up, but not the scroll pane or the radio buttons. It should show up inside of the black rectangle at the bottom of this image:
[image: Image of the problem]

Comment: consider simplifying your code and your problem to the smallest code that *compiles*, *runs* and demonstrates the problem directly for us, a [mre].

Comment: Note that the content JPanel likely has a preferred size of 0, 0, and likely it is not showing in the scroll pane because it is quite small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you didn't include a MRE and I don't see the declaration of your class but I'm guessing you are using:

```
public class ToolbarPanel extends JComponent
```

The problem is that by default a JComponent doesn't have a layout manager so you won't see your components.

If you use:

```
public class ToolbarPanel extends JPanel
```

It will be a little better, but all the components will be displayed in a small square.

So you will also want to add

```
setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
```

to your constructor.

Note:

This is why a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) should be included with every question. We should not have to spend time guessing what you may or may not be doing.

Comment: I changed it from JComponent to JPanel and added `setLayout( new BorderLayout() );` to the constructor and it worked. Thank you for the info